# How to run python file in Buidroot with sh?

Tags: python-3.x, buildroot

I am using buildroot to make my OS ready for use, although I packaged python3 interpreter in the .img file, it still came up with "-sh: python3: not found" what should I do? Is there a way to manually install python3 in buildroot?Or is there a way to use python interpreter?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify in buildroot menuconfig if BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON3 is enabled.[python3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9qNQ.png)

Once the build is complete check output/build/ for python3 package folder and verify if .files-list.txt has /usr/bin/python3.

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of code, rather provide the code block so that the OP can easily copy and use the code

Comment: I'm sorry, there's no code in the image I have posted, it is buildroot config help for python3.